# Row total in Pivot Table - ms sql

Tags: sql-server

I need a row total column in a PIVOT

MS SQL Query is as under but the Total Column is displaying NULL values.

Request assistance.

Thank you

```
 SELECT *
 FROM   ( SELECT    DATENAME(yyyy, Request_Date) AS Year ,
                DATENAME(mm, Request_Date) AS Month ,
                Project_Name ,
                Status ,
                Request_Type ,
                COUNT(Test_Name) AS Test
      FROM      request_details2
      GROUP BY  DATENAME(yyyy, Request_Date) ,
                DATENAME(mm, Request_Date) ,
                Request_Type ,
                Status ,
                Project_Name
      HAVING    ( Request_Type = 'Test Request' )
    ) AS s PIVOT
( SUM(Test) FOR [Month] IN ( January, february, March, April, May, June, July,
                         August, September, October, November, December,
                         Total ) )



AS piv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query will work for the desired purpose :)

```
SELECT
year, Project_Name,Status ,  Request_Type , 
  January = SUM(January),
  february  = SUM(february),
  March    = SUM(March),
  April    = SUM(April),
  May     = SUM(May),
  June   = SUM(June),
  July   = SUM(July),
  August   = SUM(August),
  September   = SUM(September),
  October   = SUM(October),
  October   = SUM(November),
  December   = SUM(December),
  Total    = SUM(ISNULL(January,0) + ISNULL(february,0) + ISNULL(March,0)  + ISNULL(April,0)  + ISNULL(May,0)  + 
  ISNULL(June,0)  +ISNULL(July,0)  + ISNULL(August,0)  + ISNULL(September,0)  + ISNULL(October,0)  + ISNULL(November,0)  + ISNULL(December,0) )
FROM (
SELECT *
 FROM   ( SELECT    DATENAME(yyyy, Request_Date) AS Year ,
                DATENAME(mm, Request_Date) AS Month ,
                Project_Name ,
                Status ,
                Request_Type ,
                COUNT(Test_Name) AS Test
      FROM      request_details2
      GROUP BY  DATENAME(yyyy, Request_Date) ,
                DATENAME(mm, Request_Date) ,
                Request_Type ,
                Status ,
                Project_Name
      HAVING    ( Request_Type = 'Test Request' )
    ) AS s PIVOT
( SUM(Test) FOR [Month] IN ( January, february, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December ))
AS piv
) as b 

group by 
year, Project_Name,Status ,  Request_Type
```

Comment: Hi Paali...many thanks for your support...but no joy...it says column b.year is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Query working .... Tested....but giving NULL Values in Total

Comment: Hi Aditya, I am getting a perfect numerical value in Total :) I edited my comment include a snapshot of my result

Comment: Hi Palli, I am extracting month from the Request_date column...there is no Month Column in the table...

Comment: Aditya, Even after removing the month column it worked. Actually I added a month column initially but then realized it was extracted from date so I wasn't using it in my query. I don't understand why you are getting NULL as an answer. May be some difference in data structure or table

Comment: I have checked the query a couple of time...Let me check..Thanks for your time and help

Comment: Ok I got it when the sum(Test) in months is NULL the total is NULL see the corrected query now. I have corrected it to tackle null values Run the query now after my last edit

Comment: WOWWWW...Works like a dream...thanks a tons Paali